# Why can't i define a variable recursively in a code block?

Tags: scala, recursion

Why can't i define a variable recursively in a code block?

```
scala> {
     | val test: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: test
     | }
<console>:9: error: forward reference extends over definition of value test
              val test: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: test
                                            ^

scala> val test: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: test
test: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
```

`lazy` keyword solves this problem, but i can't understand why it works without a code block but throws a compilation error in a code block.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Note that in the REPL

```
scala> val something = "a value"
```

is evaluated more or less as follows:

```
object REPL$1 {
  val something = "a value"
}
import REPL$1._
```

So, any `val`(or `def`, etc) is a member of an internal REPL helper object.

Now the point is that classes (and objects) allow forward references on their members:

```
object ForwardTest {
  def x = y // val x would also compile but with a more confusing result
  val y = 2
}
ForwardTest.x == 2
```

This is not true for `val`s inside a block. In a block everything must be defined in linear order. Thus `val`s are no members anymore but plain variables (or values, resp.). The following does not compile either:

```
def plainMethod = { // could as well be a simple block
  def x = y
  val y = 2
  x
}

<console>: error: forward reference extends over definition of value y
     def x = y
             ^
```

It is not recursion which makes the difference. The difference is that classes and objects allow forward references, whereas blocks do not.

Answer (score 4):

I'll add that when you write:

```
object O {
  val x = y
  val y = 0
}
```

You are actually writing this:

```
object O {
  val x = this.y
  val y = 0
}
```

That little `this` is what is missing when you declare this stuff inside a definition.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior depends on different val initialization times. If you type `val x = 5` directly to the REPL, `x` becomes a member of an object, which values can be initialized with a default value (null, 0, 0.0, false). In contrast, values in a block can not initialized by default values.

This tends to different behavior:

```
scala> class X { val x = y+1; val y = 10 }
defined class X

scala> (new X).x
res17: Int = 1

scala> { val x = y+1; val y = 10; x } // compiles only with 2.9.0
res20: Int = 11
```

In Scala 2.10 the last example does not compile anymore. In 2.9.0 the values are reordered by the compiler to get it to compile. There is a [bug report](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4856) which describes the different initialization times.

Comment: The last example doesn’t compile. (Which of course is the whole point in question.)

Comment: @Debilski: You are right, with 2.10 it does not compile anymore. I used 2.9.0 to get this to compile as mentioned in the bug report.

Comment: I was using 2.9.1-1. So it must’ve been changed in between.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that a Scala Worksheet in the Eclipse-based Scala-IDE (v4.0.0) does not behave like the REPL as one might expect (e.g. https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started says "Worksheets are like a REPL session on steroids") in this respect, but rather like the definition of one long method: That is, forward referencing val definitions (including recursive val definitions) in a worksheet must be made members of some object or class.