# What are odd names like $read and $iw doing in the reified expression?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Here are some snippets from my Scala prompt. I import the reflection API and try reifying some expressions, as described in the [docs here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html).

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
scala> val str = "Duck I says."

scala> ru.showRaw(ru.reify(println(2)))
res40: String = Expr(Apply(Select(Select(This(newTypeName("scala")), 
    newTermName("Predef")), newTermName("println")), List(Literal(Constant(2)))))

scala> ru.showRaw(ru.reify(str.length))    
res41: String = Expr(Apply(Select(Select(Select(Select(Select(Ident($line4), 
    newTermName("$read")), newTermName("$iw")), newTermName("$iw")), 
    newTermName("str")), newTermName("length")), List()))
```

I did not expect to see these symbols `$line4`, `$read`, and `$iw` in the second one. What are they and why are they there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`val str ...` in REPL is actually not a locale variable, but a property of some object. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955585/406435).

Wrap variable definition and `reify` call with code block like this:

```
{
  val str = ...
  showRaw{reify {...}}
}
```